# While creating directory entry of a windows machine, I am getting access is denied exception

Tags: c#, windows, directoryentry

I am trying to create the directory entry of a computer using the following statements :

```
try{
      String Path = String.Format("WinNT://{0}", machineName);
         DirectoryEntry de = new DirectoryEntry(Path);
         de.Username = AdminName;
         de.Password = password;


         if (de.Guid!= null)

            {

             Console.Writeline("Exiting the method. Returning the created directory entry for the path = " + de.Path + "and Administrator Account " + de.Username);
            }


      }
      catch (COMException exception)
      {
             Console.WriteLine("Got the exception"+exception.Message);

             throw new Exception(exception.Message);
       }
```

Here I am using a user who is a member of Administrators group to login.Also with the same credentials I am able to remote desktop to the system. I am getting the following error of type UnauthorizedAccessException  :

```
"Access is denied"
```

Comment: Try running your program as administrator. Does the problem still exist if you do so?

Comment: I am running the program from my desktop.And I am logged in as the local administrator.

Comment: In Vista and higher you have to use UAC. Right click exe-file, run as administrator. If you are debugging from VS, then you have to run VS itself as administrator. It may be possible to embed manifest, which required administrator rights when you start exe-file automatically (and VS in this case will offer you a choice to restart itself with administrator rights when you try to debug such application).

Comment: You have to be the admin of the remote machine, not the local one.  Manipulating admin passwords in your source code is surely the reason that IT staff won't give you access to the account you need.

Comment: I am using an account which is a member of the Administrators group of the target machine.Still I am getting the error.

Comment: @Sinar : This is working fine for Windows 7 but it is not working for Windows 2008 r2.I am running the program from the visual studio as the same user for both the cases.

Comment: Also from a different machine, I am able to get the directory entry of the windows machine.So doesnot seem to be the access issue with the windows machine.